# Integral Limits Placement in LaTeX

Tags: macros, positioning

I'm using a converter to generate LaTeX codes. The converter gives me the results below for integral and sum. limits are above and below.  I want sum and other symbol limits as given in (1) but integral limits as given (2). I don't want to change the code for integrals manually every time. What command should I use?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\underset{1}{\overset{2}{\mathop \int }}\,{{x}^{2}}dx,\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\mathop \sum }}\,i,~\underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty }{\mathop \bigcup }}\,{{B}_{i}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_{1}^{2} x^2~dx
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: Why are you using `underset`?

Comment: The converter does a very bad work.

Comment: egreg. you are right. if it can't be changed by a command, can you suggest a different converter?                     Sigur. converter gives that.

Comment: What is this converter?

Comment: mathtype toggletex

Comment: @mert If killing mosquitos with a sledgehammer damages the walls, it's probably better to change the tool. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The converter shouldn't use `\overset` and `\underset`: it's just wrong!

Correct code for the examples is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\int_{1}^{2}x^{2}\,dx,\quad
\sum_{i=1}^{n}i,\quad
\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The converter is doing bad work: it adds really useless constructions (which are wrong in some cases).

[image]

Comment: An alternate usage for integral is   $\int\limits_{1}^{2}x^{2}\,dx$

Comment: @ferahfeza I don't think that `\limits` is what the OP wants.

Comment: you might want to mention that `\overset` and `\underset` don't even put the limits in the right position; compare with `\int\limits`.